# MySQL Workbench import limit

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import data from a csv file to MySQL Workbench 6.3.5 using the table data import wizard. I have about 400000 rows of data but the wizard is importing only 27016 rows of data.

Is it a bug or limit on importing the data through MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Can you do it from the command line and see if you get the same result?

Comment: I would check the input file around line 27016. Perhaps it is malformatted.

Comment: Did you get any error or status message?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr Nope, i didn't get any error or status message.

Comment: @Shadow csv file i am using is generated using mysql-workbench only

Comment: You can generate malfomatted csv outputs, which cannot be imported back to a database.

Comment: Does the mysql log file show that mysql was restarted?

Comment: What is the physical size of the import?  Might want to compare it against `max_allowed_packet`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my data import.

I opened the CSV in Notepad++ and found that Excel had saved it with an ANSI encoding rather than UTF-8. When I swapped the encoding to UTF-8 it highlighted the fact that there were invalid characters on the row my import was failing on.

I manually removed these characters and the import worked perfectly. It might be worth sanitizing your input data in a similar way.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that while importing you are using "Don't limit"
option in MySQL Workbench. If you are not able to find that option then you can use the following query.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'file path' 
INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS LIMIT 0, N;
```

where N-the number of rows in the csv file